# Populate a RadioButton

Tags: c#, html

I have a class called [SchoolingLevels], with this code:

```
public List<SelectListItem> schoolingLevels = new List<SelectListItem>();

public List<SelectListItem> Populate()
{
        schoolingLevels.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Primary incomplete", Value = "Primary incomplete" });
        schoolingLevels.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Primary", Value = "Primary" });
        schoolingLevels.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Secondary incomplete", Value = "Secondary incomplete" });
        schoolingLevels.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Secondary", Value = "Secondary" });
        schoolingLevels.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Higher education incomplete", Value = "Higher education incomplete" });
        schoolingLevels.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Higher education", Value = "Higher education" });
        schoolingLevels.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Post-graduation/MBA", Value = "Post-graduation/MBA" });
        return schoolingLevels;
}
```

And I want to populate my RadioButton based on this List..

In my controller:

```
ViewBag.Scholarity = new SchoolingLevels().Populate();
```

In my view:

```
@Html.RadioButton("Scholarity", "a")
```

It's not working.. (I tested with DropDown and works perfectly), isn't it possible to RadioButton?

**EDIT**

I tried it:

```
@foreach (var myValue in ViewBag.Scholarity)
{ 
   Html.RadioButton("Scholarity","Value")
}
```

It seems work, but where can I put the NAME of the radiobuttons?

Ty.

Comment: How is it not working? Does anything happen at all or does it populate incorrectly?

Comment: I don't think so, for dropdown it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below code will help you:

```
@foreach (var myValue in ViewBag.Scholarity)
{
    string text = myValue.Text.ToString();
    string val = myValue.Value.ToString();
   @Html.RadioButton("ScholarityList", val);
   <span>@text</span>
}
```

or  Create your custom HTML helper like below:

```
public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonList(this HtmlHelper helper, 
string NameOfList, List<string> RadioOptions) {

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// put a similar foreach here
foreach(var myOption in RadioOptions) {
    sb.Append(helper.RadioButton(NameOfList, myOption));
}

return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
```

}

```
@Html.RadioButtonList("ScholarityList", ViewBag.Scholarity);
```

Please follow the link to know more : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/657164/Radio-Button-List-for-MVC

Comment: For me, not exists RadioButtonList, only RadioButton and RadioButtonFor..

And the first solution, I tried @Html.RadioButton("ScholarityList", "Value"), but I can't name the radiobuttons.. only appear the check option

Comment: @developer033 I have edited the answer. Can you please check this?

Comment: Thank you very much Nivs.

My final code:

Html.RadioButton("Scholarity", value, new { id = "Scholarity", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
<span> text </span> <br /> 

(I can't use "@"..)

Btw, is there any option in "display:.." to show every radio button below the other? Like repeat direction:vertical in ASP.NET? I didn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

you can also iterate through your list and change the code below according to the data you have.

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.item, "Yes") @:Yes
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.item, "No") @:No
}
```